# Save a string with a photo and return them

Tags: objective-c, uiimagepickercontroller, asihttprequest

I have a label on top of the image view.
Every time some one pushes the button the label is filled with a string that comes from a server.
I have a button that calls the picker to select a photo from the picker but the label obviously keeps empty..

How can i make sure the string will be saved with the photo and when i call it back with the picker it fills the label again...

I need some tips/help...

i am using ASIHTTPREQUEST asynchronical call to fill the label...so it does not hang up...thats best practice right ? or should i use nsurl and nsstring with format ?

Answer (score 0):

you may use imageview's tag and store each string with tag of image view.

Comment: to clarify things a bit: the button i press to fill the label is the same button to shoot a photo ( it shoots a photo and fills the label at once)

Answer (score 0):

Somethings are not clear here :-

1>from the client sid eyou can send a request to server with the image that has been changed and get the corresponding string(in a table probably you have have to store string for each image).

2>You might use a dictionary to store key(string) for every corresponding imageName and store it in a dictionary and if you want persistent storage you may use coredata or sqlite.

To ensure that both the image and string are shown at same time you can show an activityIndicator.

Comment: to clarify things a bit: the button i press to fill the label is the same button to shoot a photo ( it shoots a photo and fills the label at once) 

Hmm so for easy handling the photo that is taken inside the app has to get a generated name like Photo001, next Photo002... so that i can find the same saved string ?

Comment: yes you can save the data according to your image name..a nsmutabledictionary would be a nice idea to save things without persistency..store it in appdelegate the dictionaty and acces it via appdelegate